# Geographic rasters in three.js scene

Tags: three.js, wms

I want to view some rasters in my three.js scene.
I thought to use cesium for that, but it was too slow when I loaded more than 1000 moving objects to the scene.
So I decided to go back to three.js with some simple cylindrical projection.

Is there an easy way to do build something like "WmsMaterial" ?
The material has to take the textures from some wms or tile server like:
http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/4/5/9

And change the level of the tile according to the zoom level. 
Any ideas how to do this in the simply ?

Answer (score 3):

On the zoom changing, you can request the tile with a REST request and load it as texture then create a material with the texture. Manage a cache to not request a tile already downloaded

Comment: Nice answer but would be great if you share some examples.